# Insert into MySQL x number of times?

Tags: php, phpquery

I want to create a temp database in MySQL. The row's content are taken from an external page which I use PHPQuery to parse. The number of times for `for` loop runs is also taken from that page, running the amount of times that there are elements present on the page.

The following code barely works. I assumed it would run the code `$number` of times, where `$i` increases by one each time it runs. This way, it would insert `$new[0]`, `$new[1]`, `$new[2]`, etc. into the database. The problem is, it only inserts the last instance.

Say `$number` is 11, it will only insert `$new[11]` into the database.

```
$server = "localhost";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$database = "***";
$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$number = pq('.trafficbriefs:contains(\'SCHOOLS\')') -> parent() -> find('.maintext') -> length();
for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
    $test = pq('.trafficbriefs:contains(\'SCHOOLS\')') -> parent() -> find('.maintext') -> eq($i) -> text();
    $new[$i] = $test;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Temp (School) ";
    $sql .= "VALUES ('$new[$i]')";
}

if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
        echo "Added to database.";
    }

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: I cant see anything executing the sql inside the for loop?

Comment: @WayneC I updated my OP with the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever does the `mysql_query` also needs to be inside that loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if thats what you need but this code is going to build a query first, then execute it once. Yhis query is going to insert everything you wanted to insert in one go. This is going to be a lot faster if the `$number` is big.

```
$server = "localhost";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$database = "***";
$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$number = pq('.trafficbriefs:contains(\'SCHOOLS\')')->parent()->find('.maintext')->length();
$queryParts = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
    $test = pq('.trafficbriefs:contains(\'SCHOOLS\')')->parent()->find('.maintext')->eq($i)->text();
    $queryParts[] = '("' . $test . '")';
}
if (empty($queryParts)) {
    throw new Exception('Nothing to insert');
}
$query = 'INSERT INTO Temp (School) VALUES ' . implode(', ', $queryParts);
if (!mysql_query($query, $con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "Added to database.";
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) 
{
    $test = pq('.trafficbriefs:contains(\'SCHOOLS\')') -> parent() -> find('.maintext') -> eq($i) -> text();
    $new[$i] = $test;
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO Temp (School) ";
    $sql .= "VALUES ('$new[$i]');";
}
```

Concatenates each statement and separates them with semi-colon